# Help solve the age related particle crowd “particles age”, or with trigger collision

Tags: animation, particles, animation-nodes

the problem is:
particles move along a curve, using animated form with Character-1 (several cycles of run animation, tied to particle age, so the crowd doesn’t run in sync + at the end, death animation)

or when colliding with a trigger object, particles change animation from Personage-1 as in the first example, but with a single looped animation of running to Personage-1 (single animation of death)

I attached a screenshot of how this is done in 3ds Max

[image]

Comment: Hello, it is quite hard to understand what exactly is your question

Comment: Hi! In general, the question is - how to synchronize the linked animation of particles to their age

Comment: Okay ! The tool that comes to mind is the animation nodes (free) add-on https://animation-nodes.com/ Steep learning curve, but you seem fluent in nodes already so it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but it seems that the animation nodes, like aliens, all believe in them, but nothing definitive on the subject. Even a description of a simple setup: character runs for 2 seconds - died